# Ionic 4 modal with transparent background doesn't work

Tags: ionic4

I try to make a modal with a transparent background, but I can't find the solution, the solutions provided in the forum do not work in my case, I will thank you if you can help me, thank you very much!

**global.scss**

```
.modal-answer .modal-wrapper {
    background: transparent !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:40%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 70%;
    display: block; 
    border-radius: 1em; 
 }
```

**modal-answer-page.scss**

```
ion-content{
    --background: transparent;
}
```

**caller.ts**

```
import { ModalAnswersPage} from '../modal-answers/modal-answers.page';

..........

const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalAnswersPage,
      cssClass: 'modal-answer',
      componentProps: {
        rpta: this.ok_bad_time
      }
    });
```

Comment: make sure you global.scss is added in angular.json

Comment: thanks, yes, it is included

Comment: then it should work. can you please create Stackblitz for your code.